# Mysteries issue on Angular ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have dynamic `select`(or `dropdown`) control as shown below.It's working fine.But it has some mysteries issue.Can you please tell me how to solve that? I think this is a problem on `ngFor` loop's `index`.Maybe a cache thing or like that.Any thoughts, please?

**Note:** I have used one-way data bind with template driven form.

**.html**

```
<div *ngIf="question?.type=='dropdown'">
      <ion-note>{{question?.index}} {{question?.prompt}}*</ion-note><br/><br/>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-select name="{{question?.name}}" placeholder="Select" #name5="ngModel" ngModel>
            <ion-option *ngFor="let i of inputs;let index = index" value="{{index}}">{{i.display}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <div text-right>
        <button ion-button type="button" (click)="goToNext(currentQuestionCode,name5)">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It retrieves data from the JSON file.

**.ts**

```
  getQuestionsAndInputs(inputs: any, questionCode: string): void {

     _.some(inputs, (value, key) => {//get inputs
          if (key == questionCode) {
            this.inputs = value;
            return true;
          }
        });
}
```

**A subset of the JSON file.**

```
 "28903243": [
        {
            "encode": "4:30pm",
            "display": "4:30pm",
            "label": ""
        },
        {
            "encode": "4:45pm",
            "display": "4:45pm",
            "label": ""
        },
        {
            "encode": "5:00pm",
            "display": "5:00pm",
            "label": ""
        },
        {
            "encode": "5:15pm",
            "display": "5:15pm",
            "label": ""
        },
        {
            "encode": "5:30pm",
            "display": "5:30pm",
            "label": ""
        },
],
```

First `select` component where it shows correctly.

[image]

I have selected 2nd item (`index = 1`).

[image]

When I press the next button and bring the 2nd `select` component it automatically shows the 2nd item as the selected one (`index = 1`) on that collection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the component side of this?

Comment: Please see the update @suraj

Comment: gotoNext loads the next question?

Comment: Yes, exactely.This is the one question code`"28903243":` @suraj

Comment: you are using the same page to load another question.. so your `inputs` are reset as it is fetched again.. but `name5` is not is it?

Comment: Actually whole above HTML is being regenerated according to the new question on the same page.Here I have used `name5` to send the user's feedback to the `ts` file.That part is working fine. @suraj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143604/discussion-between-suraj-and-sampath).

Comment: Yes, Your solution worked.Can you please put that as an answer? Thanks. @suraj

Comment: OK.. Added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name5` value set by the user is not getting reset for the next question.

You need to have 2 way binding to reset the value once it is sent for each question.

```
<ion-select name="{{question?.name}}" placeholder="Select" [(ngModel)]="selectedIndex"> 
<ion-option *ngFor="let i of inputs;let index = index" value="{{index}}">{{i.display}}</ion-option> 
</ion-select>
```

In the component, `this.selectedIndex = null`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell, but what I understood, that this is a survey with questions to be loaded upon each `next` press. The only issue I can see is that the `ion-select` is bound to `ngModel` which is the same value shared across all questions. So, once it is set with the first question, the next questions will read the same value.

I think you should bind it is value to an indexed array.

Comment: Here we have 2 different JSON collections and the component itself is being created dynamically. You can see that on the images. I don't know why it has shared the same `index` here. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: And also,  I have used one-way data bind with template driven form. `#name5="ngModel" ngModel`

Comment: Can you try to make the binding as `[ngModel]=answers[question?.index]` where answers is an array of any in the component.ts file.

Comment: I think it is not sharing the `index` It is sharing the value of the selected dropdown.